# How to upload edge impulse arduino library to esp32 cam

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

When I tried to upload the Edge Impulse library to Arduino IDE and upload the code to esp32 cam, Arduino IDE shows an error message: no module named cfloat.

Maybe there is a module named cfloat but I have not installed it. Where can I install cfloat?